# floating point operations

Tags: algorithm

i  have read that some machine can't express exaclty floating point number for example 1.1
let's take code

```
float x=0.1;
do{

x+=0.1;
printf("%f\n",x);
} while(x!=1.1);
```

this code  never finished  how can i make that code finish? maybe convert it to double or?

Comment: You are not supposed to use equality comparisons on floating point numbers.

Comment: This is my favorite explanation of why floating point numbers, of any precision or type, cannot exactly represent all real numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary/1089026#1089026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, checking "<" will do the trick:

```
float x=0.1;
do{

x+=0.1;
printf("%f\n",x);
} while(x<1.05);
```

In general, you should test against an "epsilon". Look [here](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

For numerical problems, it is common to specify an epsilon of accuracy:

```
bool within_epsilon(float x, float y, float e) {
    if (abs(x - y) > e) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

The epsilon you choose will change your accuracy, and the epsilon you *can* choose is dependent on your floating point implementation: [Machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Comment: +1 for referring to epsilon, since this will enable people to google for this information in an easier way

Answer (score 2):

For example, compare within an acceptable margin. I.e.

```
while (abs(x-1.1)>0.001);
```

Doubles will have the same issue, just with more precision. Some languages also offer you rational types, where you can specify a number as the fraction 1/10, or fixed point data types.

Answer (score 0):

Work in fixed point, for that kind of task.

The [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28VS.71%29.aspx) type for example might help. It's not the solution for all problems though.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do code precisely like you are saying then you want to use a type like decimal (where available) which is a base 10 floating point implementation rather than a base 2.

Further reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point